# C# Why do I get duplicate records back when I return data from SQL to a dataset?

Tags: winforms, datagridview, duplicates, dataset, records

Im new to C#, so bear with me. Im using C#, a Form, and SQL Server 2012.

I have written some code that uses a Background Worker (from the form designer) and a progress bar to illustrate to the user the percentage of data that needs to be loaded from a SQL query until all records are completely read.

The problem Im having is that when the Worker is completed, I get many duplicate records listed in the datagridview. I should be getting only 14 returned records from my query, but I get many more (which are duplicates).

Im not sure why? Im sure there is a bug here (and that my beginnner code can be improved).

Can someone help my understand why Im getting duplicate records once the worker completes? My code is below

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;
        bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgw_DoWork);
        bgw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgw_ProgressChanged);
        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgw_RunWorkerCompleted);

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);

        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();

    }

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        string query = "Select * from Stars_Pillars";

        string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection cnn;

        connetionString = "Server=xxx\\xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;";

        cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, cnn);


        //DataSet ds = new DataSet();



        try
        {

            cnn.Open();


            int resda, startrow, pagesize, pageno;

            pagesize = getRowCount();
            progressBar1.Maximum = pagesize;
            pageno = 1;

            ds.Tables.Clear();
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();


            while (true)

            {
                if (!bgw.CancellationPending) 
                {
                    startrow = pageno;

                    resda = da.Fill(ds, startrow, pagesize, "Stars_Pillars");
                    if (resda == 0)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
                        int percents = (pageno * 100 / pagesize);
                        bgw.ReportProgress(percents, pageno);
                        pageno++;

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }

            }


            da.Dispose();
            cnn.Close();
            cnn.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
        }

    }



    private void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        progressBar1.PerformStep();

    }

    private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Maximum;
        progressBar1.Visible = false;

       dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

    }


    private int getRowCount()
    {
        int count = 0;
        string connetionString;

        connetionString = "Server=xxxx\\xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx;";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        string sql = "SELECT COUNT(Serial_Number) FROM [Stars_Pillars]";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                count = (int)dr[0];
            }
        }
        catch { }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a **lot** of improvements to make in your code...you should never use `while (true)` 
 it is extremely bad practice and you can end with infinite loop. 
also, there is no way to measure and show progress of filling a `dataset` with `dataAdapter`.
if the operation takes time show a Marquee `style` progress bar.
for start try this code to load data from database to the `DataSet` object:

```
 private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
    try 

    {
    string query = "Select * from Stars_Pillars";
    connetionString = "Server=xxx\\xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;";
    using(cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
    {
            cnn.Open();
            using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, cnn))
            {
                    adapter.Fill(ds);
                    cnn.Close();
            }
    }

    } catch (Exception ex) {

    // handle errors here and close connetion if its open
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello jonathana - I have the code you presented already working from a couple of days ago. The progress bar also works correctly in my code. The issue is that once the worker is completed, and I use the statement "dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];"   the output is duplicate records in the datagridview....Im not sure what part of the code is creating the duplicate records in the datagriview?

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting an exception with your code. 
You cannot access UI element from bgwDoWork()

The below line must be failing.

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
```

Please check.

Comment: Hello Hitesh, I removed that line and I still get the duplicate records in my datagridview.

Comment: # CsharpNewGuy17Can - you try executing the same line from inside of bgw_ProgressChanged() and see please?

Comment: Hitesh, that did not work either. Im still getting duplicate rows.  It appears that each time the line "resda = da.Fill(ds, startrow, pagesize, "Stars_Pillars");"  executes in the While loop, the code is adding the same dataset (ds) repeatedly.